# How to connect and transfer data between unity and arduino by wifi

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino

I want to know how to create a game from unity that can control the players by the data sent from an arduino via wifi. Help me please!!!!!!

I am a newbie in unity, any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Do you want to connect the Arduino directly to the PC that is running Unity or do you want the arduino to use Internet? If you just want to connect it to the PC I would recommend the Uduino package that simplifies your life a lot, check it out [here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/uduino-arduino-and-unity-communication-simple-fast-and-stable-78402).

Comment: This is a very broad question that is difficult to answer.  For example, there are multiple WiFi solutions for Arduino so you need to specify which you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `TCPListener` in unity that listens for incoming connections. On the Arduino side you will need to create a `EthernetClient` and connect to the listener.

Here is some documentation on the Arduino side: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConnect